# Images hangs and takes too long to populate from service

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to fetch images on a button click in Viewcontroller B .After the image is received as response,I use the url of images to populate the imageviews on viewcontroller.But,it is taking too long to get populated and also hangs while scrolling.Is there any way to scroll the view smoothly without freezing and get the response little early.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use dispatch async for image retrieve, namely, don't do it on main queue.

Apple Doc: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) , ^{
       methodToPopulateImageView();
    });`
With this change, your app wont hang and wait for image to show up.

Answer (score 0):

This line should not be in main queue

```
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[responseArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CategoryImage"]]];
```

you may change to something like this

```
  NSString *getImagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",n1.Id]];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath])
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
        cell.leftImageV.image =img;
        [cell.activity stopAnimating];
        cell.activity.hidden=YES;
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.activity startAnimating];
         cell.activity.hidden=NO;

        cell.leftImageV.image = nil;

        NSLog(@"xdasdxsadxa %@",n1.mainImgStr);

        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
            __block NSData * imageData  = nil;
            dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{ 

                imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:n1.mainImgStr]];

                //Add the file name
                [imageData writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

            });

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if(imageData)
                { 
                    [self.collectionView reloadData];

                } 
            });
        }); 
    }
```